# ASP MVC Entity Framework Code First Mysql UTF 8 Database

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config

I'm creating a database using EF Code First and MySql from an ASP MVC project.  The problem is that I'm not able to set the encoding to UTF8.

From what I've read I have to set `Charset=utf8;`. But it's not working.

```
<add name="ArticleEntities" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=db; Uid=user; Pwd=pass$;Charset=utf8;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: maybe try with dash: `Charset=utf-8`

Comment: I get an error if i do that

Comment: actually, what do you mean by 'it's not working'? db not being created? or created with wrong encoding?

Comment: Instead of Silivașu  i get Siliva?u

Comment: if it's not critical to you, maybe just manually set encoding for db  in phpMyAdmin

Comment: It's really not an option, it's still in development, and that means that every time i want to update my models i would have to update the dabase by hand